# Replace method wont work with Datetime objects and IF statements in Python

Tags: python, datetime, replace

I am trying to run this code:

```
if initial_hour_obj.hour == 8:
    print (initial_hour_obj)
    initial_hour_obj.replace(hour = 10)
    print (initial_hour_obj)

2022-03-23 08:30:00
2022-03-23 08:30:00
```

but the replace method wont work.
If I try to print a message after the if statement to see if my datetime obj hour is equal to the integer 8, it prints my message, so the evaluation is working, and if I try the .replace() method outside of the if, it also works, any ideas why they wont work together?

thanks

Comment: Replace() returns the result of said replacing, which you arent saving anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, got it now, initial_hour_obj = initial_hour_obj.replace(hour = 10) would have the effect I need

Answer (score 2):

When you are running `replace()`, it is returning the result, it is not storing the result in `initial_hour_obj`.

So, you have to do this:

```
if initial_hour_obj.hour == 8:
    print (initial_hour_obj)
    initial_hour_obj = initial_hour_obj.replace(hour = 10)
    print (initial_hour_obj)
```